# SQL Select All in Table that have same ID as '..'

Tags: mysql, sql

Basically, I have a table of support users, and there are different user's of different levels in different departments.

So let's say I basically have the following table:

```
id | userID | deptID | level
1      1        1        1
2     119       1        2
3      2        1        3
4     101       2        1
5     104       2        2
```

And I have the `id` number, so let's say, I want to get all users with the same `deptID` as the user in `id`:`3`, thus returning the first three lines.

What kind of SQL statement would that be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the following query, that contains a subquery:

```
SELECT * 
FROM <table> 
WHERE deptID=(
              SELECT deptID FROM <table> WHERE userID=3
             )
```

Comment: @Chud37 they are known as subqueries

Comment: They're called sub-selects.

Comment: perhaps because you have no user with `userId=3` in your table

Comment: oh right, not `userID` but `id`, Works beautifully! Thank you, I've learnt something new :)

Comment: Remember changing <table> for your table name.

Comment: @fedorqui, sorry, the damn time restrictions here prevented me and I forgot about it.  I've marked it now.  Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @Chud37 no problem :) glad that it worked to you... and yes, this 15 minutes thing makes us forget about accepting!

Answer (score 2):

```
select  u.*
from    users u join users u2 on u.deptID = u2.deptID
where   u2.id = 3
```

Comment: Untested, I'd have said `JOIN ... WHERE` was a mistake, but seems at least MySQL swallows it without a complaint :) `JOIN ... ON` is what other databases require though.

Comment: yep, it is still valid SQL, but no need to be so old-skool about it. answer edited...

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM Users
WHERE deptID IN 
    (SELECT deptID FROM Users WHERE userID = 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select my.*
from myTable my
join myTable myt on my.deptID = myt.deptID
where myt.id = 3
```

Comment: I think that's supposed to be `where myt.id = 3`...?

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from data where deptid in (select deptid from data where id=3);
```

Use this query